# Using JTextField - Unable to convert value to int

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, parseint

I want to get the selected value from `JComboBox`, search it in database and update the quantity in database with the value in `JTextField`. Here is the code :

```
    Object selected = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    String album = (String)selected;
    int qty=Integer.parseInt(jTextField7.getText());
    String query2="update  productlist set QtyAvail=? " +
                "where Album=?";
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement ps2=con.prepareStatement(query2);
            ps2.setInt(1, qty);
            ps2.setString(2,album);
            int res1=ps2.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException:
  For input string: " 1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at AddProductPanel.jButton2ActionPerformed(AddProductPanel.java:341)
    at AddProductPanel.access$4(AddProductPanel.java:335)
    at AddProductPanel$5.actionPerformed(AddProductPanel.java:133)
```

I entered value '1' in the text field.

Answer (score 5):

There is a white space in the the string input to `parseInt()` , use `trim()`

Answer (score 4):

> I want to get the selected value from `JComboBox`, search it in database and update the quantity in database with the value in `JTextField`.

- use [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) with `Number Formatter`
- or maybe better will be usage of [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) with `SpinnerNumberModel`
- avoids to parse between data types, you can control over the inputted value (min - max - ev. the range - decimal form)

Comment: *"or maybe better will be usage of `JSpinner` with `SpinnerNumberModel`"*  I was waiting for *someone* to suggest that (best IMO) alternative to the general problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your string contains a white space.

Use trim before parse :

```
int qty=Integer.parseInt(jTextField7.getText().trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nivedita Gautam : It seems that `a blank` space is appended before `1`. 
Try to use the following statement:

```
int qty = Integer.parseInt(jTextField7.getText().trim());
```